# Saving remote image to Documents/Images Folder

Tags: iphone, cocoa

I've checked about every answer to the other questions posted here but no answers seem to work.

Im trying to save an image( e.g http://dl.kr.org/logos/dl-small.gif) on a website to my Documents/Images folder on the iphone.

Can someone paste me the code i need , i've tried long and small answers none of them work

Comment: i've been using about every piece of code there is on this site :D   2 mins after i've submitted this question i find the error that's been keeping me all day ,   a wrong url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://dl.kr.org/logos/dl-small.gif"]];

NSString *imagePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/dl-small.gif", [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0]];

[data writeToFile:imagePath atomically:NO];
```

Answer (score 1):

### Try this Code..

```
// Get an image from the URL below
UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.objectgraph.com/images/og_logo.png"]]];

NSLog(@"%f,%f",image.size.width,image.size.height);

// Let's save the file into Document folder.
// You can also change this to your desktop for testing. (e.g. /Users/kiichi/Desktop/)
// NSString *deskTopDir = @"/Users/kiichi/Desktop";

NSString *docDir = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];

// If you go to the folder below, you will find those pictures
NSLog(@"%@",docDir);

NSLog(@"saving png");
NSString *pngFilePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/test.png",docDir];
NSData *data1 = [NSData dataWithData:UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)];
[data1 writeToFile:pngFilePath atomically:YES];

NSLog(@"saving jpeg");
NSString *jpegFilePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/test.jpeg",docDir];
NSData *data2 = [NSData dataWithData:UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0f)];//1.0f = 100% quality
[data2 writeToFile:jpegFilePath atomically:YES];

NSLog(@"saving image done");

[image release];
```